# Jpa many-to-many relation to same entity with extra columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Im facing an issue with The following:

```
public class Person {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Relation> relations;
    ....
}

public class Relation {

     private Person person;
     private Person relatedWith;
     private String relationType;
}
```

The goal is to annotate these classes with JPA so any given person can have a relation with any other person.(thus manytomany)
The relation table should have a combined primary key consisting of the `person.id` and the `relatedWith.id`.

How can i do this? 
Thanks for your help!
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use combined primary key, use a generated one (e.g. sequence or autoincrement column for Relation table) and then you'll have two foreign keys back to the Person table.

Comment: Oops, of course. Thanks for the answer! I'll try your suggestion. I was so focussed on creating the combined key solution that I did not check any other possibilities :-)